# Update value in JSON object using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I've got a JSON object that's being submitted to a AWS Lambda NodeJS function. This JSON object has an apostrophe in one of the fields that I need to escape before it's being inserted into a MySQL database.

The object needs to stay intact as it's being stored as a JSON object in the database. I've looked at string replace functions but those won't work since this is a JSON object natively.

I'm sure there is a simple answer here, I'm just very new to NodeJS and haven't found a way after searching around for a few hours. Thanks in advance!

The field I need to update is 2.1 below:

**Example of the BAD JSON Object:**

```
{
  "field1": "ABCD1234DEFG4567",
  "field2": "FBI",
  "fieldgroup": {
    "1.1": "ABCD",
    "1.2": 20170721,
    "1.3": "ABCD",
    "2.1": "L'astName, FirstName M"
  }
}
```

**Example of the FINAL JSON object:**

```
{
  "field1": "ABCD1234DEFG4567",
  "field2": "FBI",
  "fieldgroup": {
    "1.1": "ABCD",
    "1.2": 20170721,
    "1.3": "ABCD",
    "2.1": "L''astName, FirstName M"
  }
}
```

Comment: You could convert the values to utf-8 and store it that way. https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8

Comment: To be pedantic, there is no 'JSON object', it's either JSON (unparsed -- a string) or a JS value (parsed -- an object, array, string, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const o = {
    "field1": "ABCD1234DEFG4567",
    "field2": "FBI",
    "fieldgroup": {
        "1.1": "ABCD",
        "1.2": 20170721,
        "1.3": "ABCD",
        "2.1": "L'astName, FirstName M"
      }      
   };
   
const preparedObject = prepare(o);
console.log(JSON.stringify(preparedObject, null, 4));

function prepare(o) {
  const replacedStrings = Object.keys(o)
    .filter(key => typeof o[key] === "string")
    .reduce((accu, key) => ({ ...accu, [key]: o[key].replace("'", "''") }), {});
  const preparedChildren = Object.keys(o)
    .filter(key => typeof o[key] === "object")
    .reduce((accu, key) => ({ ...accu, [key]: prepare(o[key]) }), {});
  return { ...o, ...replacedStrings, ...preparedChildren };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting the value as JSON, do a string replace on the JSON and return back as an Object, this should work.

```
let escapeSingleQuotes = json => {
  return JSON.parse(json.replace(/'/, "''"))
}
```

If you want to remove the single quotes from a JS Object, its the same as above but, convert to a string first then go back to an object

```
let escapeSingleQuotes = obj => {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/'/, "''"))
}
```

Comment: Please use `const` for functions.